# How to write a condition with more than one field with jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq, row-value-expression

I would like to write a condition like the following with JOOQ

```
AND (id,name) IN (('id1','name1'),('id2','name2'),...)
```

I tried this syntax

```
Condition condition= DSL.concat(idField,nameField).in("");
```

which generates

```
concat(cast(`id` as char), cast(`name` as char)) in ('id1name1',"id2name2",....))
```

But this solution lead to a huge performance issue by skipping indexes

I've no clue of how to get the two fields together

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation, when in fact you want to use row value expression predicates! Use jOOQ's row value expression support as documented here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/row-value-expressions

Or more specifically:

```java
// import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.row;
Condition condition = row(ID, NAME).in(row("id1", "name1"), row("id2", "name2"));
```

You might need to suppress warnings due to the generic varargs parameter in [`Row2.in(Row2...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Row2.html#in%28org.jooq.Row2...%29)

If your target database doesn't support row value expressions, jOOQ will expand the above to this predicate

```sql
(ID = 'id1' AND NAME = 'name1') OR (ID = 'id2' AND NAME = 'name2')
```